# what's that type deduced by auto?

Tags: c++, auto

In some rare situation, i will want to explicitly declare variable?

so what's the type of f4 ?

code below come from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind)

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <functional>

struct Foo {
    int data = 10;
};

int main()
{
    using namespace std::placeholders;  // for _1, _2, _3...

    Foo foo;  
    auto f4 = std::bind(&Foo::data, _1);  // bind to member data
    std::cout << f4(foo) << '\n';
}
```

## ps1: i want to declare an array of std::bind that bind to C::m1, C::m2...

```
class C
{
  string m1;
  string m2;
};
```

## ps2: decltype solve my problem, thanks everyone.

```
typedef decltype(std::bind(&C::m1, placeholders::_1)) Field;
Field foo[] = 
{
  std::bind(&C::m1, placeholders::_1);
  std::bind(&C::m2, placeholders::_1);
}
```

Comment: As stated in the linked doc: unspecified.

Comment: not having to know the type is a good thing, embrace it ;-)

Comment: It is unspecified and can always be stored in a `std::function` object of some kind (with the appropriate parameters and return type). In this case, it would be something like `std::function< int(Foo&) >`. So, if you don't want to use `auto`, or you cannot use it for whatever reason, then `std::function` is what you should use for storing the results of a `std::bind` call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to declare something that matches the type of `f4`, you can use `decltype(f4)` to specify the type:

```
decltype(f4) f5;
```

Comment: Nice.  I think you're the only one of us that saw *the real question*.

Comment: Although with the question edit, you should really suggest using `std::function`.

Answer (score 3):

Type of `f4` will be some unspecified type, returning from [std::bind](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind).
You can look at it in compiler error by using for example `TD`.

```
template<typename>
struct TD;

// in main
TD<decltype(f4)> _;
```

Note: `decltype` returns actual type of `f4`.

Note: Result of `std::bind` can be assigned to `std::function` with proper signature. For your first example it will be `std::function<int(Foo&)>`

Comment: By "look at" you mean that the compiler will spit it at you in the errors? `:)`

Answer (score 2):

just in case you'd want to introspect types again, there's a nice library: [Boost.TypeIndex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_typeindex.html) that will give you a prettyprented type.

For Clang 3.4

`type_id_with_cvr<decltype(f4)>().pretty_name()`

[is](https://travis-ci.org/d-led/test_newest_boost/builds/48319749)

`std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<int Foo::*> (std::_Placeholder<1>)>`

Answer (score 1):

The type returned from a call to `std::bind` is [**unspecified** by the standard.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind)

Each implementation is free to invent whatever type works.